# Google Wallet for Merchant isn't available in my country

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm trying to start up as a Android developer and I reasearch and found that I need an account of Google Wallet for Merchant but it isn't available in my country I reasearch a lot and didn't found more information, does anyone knows about another way of payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are considering micro-payments, you don't have to use google payment system. Paypal have been developing an sdk to implement native mobile payment for both Android and iOS.

You can learn more about sdk here:
[Paypal Mobile SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/)